# PHP: How to respond with a custom protocol other than HTTP?

Tags: php, fastcgi

My application is served by php-fpm so PHP will detect that and try to format the response to make it a valid HTTP response. I want to change that:

```
<?php
ini_set('html_errors', 0);
$x = "<body></body>";
header_remove('Content-type');
echo $x;
```

The current output (Not what I want):

```
CRLF (empty line)
<body></body>
```

I want to have a full control over php response and remove empty line at the beginning:

```
<body></body>
```

How can I do it? How can I have a full control over the output in FastCGI environment.

Comment: PHP does not add body or other HTML elements, nor does it add new lines. If you get this output, it is output by something in our PHP script. Check for whitespace at the beginning and end of your scripts.

Comment: @Gordon Actually PHP adds new line between the http header and body response to match the RFC standard in fastcgi environment . you can try the code by yourself or read the manual http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.cgi.rfc2616-headers

Comment: Ok, to clarify: you don't want to remove any newlines from the response body, but the actual newline seperating header and response body, e.g. the newline required by the CGI and HTTP specs. Also, judging by your code, you also want to remove the Content-Type that is mandatory in a CGI response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot remove the newline between the header and the response body.

They are hardcoded in the FPM engine:

- https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/sapi/fpm/fpm/fpm_main.c#L354

If you don't want the newline, put something in front of the FPM that modifies the response before returning it to the requesting client.

Comment: Thanks, appreciated.